# Get Metamask current network name when dashboard is specified as a network option using Truffle

Tags: solidity, truffle

I'm using Truffle to develop DAPP. I would like to ask if it's possible to dynamically get the network name during deployment process with `dashboard` as a spcified network. What I mean by that is I have a `deploy-config.js` file which holds different configurations for different networks. I also have a `2_deploy_MyContract.js` migration file. `MyContract` expects a struct in the constructor function as a parameter.

```
const MyContract = artifacts.require('MyContract');
const getConfig = require('../deploy-config');

module.exports = async function (deployer) {
    const config = getConfig(currently_selected_network); <-- The Problem

    await deployer.deploy(
        MyContract,
        {
            ...config.data
        }
    );
};
```

When I run `truffle migrate --reset --network dashboard` I can change the selected network using metamask any time. I would like to somehow fetch the network name it deploys to and pass it as `currently_selected_network` so my js function can provide proper config values. I think I can try specifying the network name by updating the `truffle-config.js` file and then only deploy to those predefined networks but using `dashboard` allows me to not keep the mnemonic inside the repo and sign every transaction by Metamask extension.

If you have any other ideas how to achive this goal I will be more than happy to hear it out!

This is how `deploy-config.js` looks like

```
const config = {
  network1: {
   paramA: "A"
   paramB: "B"
  },
  network2: {
   paramA: "C"
   paramB: "D"
  }
}

function getConfig(networkName) {
 switch(networkName) {
  case "network1":
   return config.network1;
  case "network2":
   return config.network2;
  default:
   return null;
}

module.exports = getConfig
```

Comment: Do you mind posting the whole deploy_My_contract.js, deploy-config-js and truffle-config.js?

Comment: `deploy_My_contract.js` looks almost exactly like the one above. I just have 2 more function calls, nothing special. `deploy-config-js` contains `config` object with two keys for different networks and a function which returns proper object depending on the network name. `truffle-config.js` is also almost empty I barely use it in this example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your migration scripts add, `network` to your anonymous function
I believe order and arg position matter.
e.g.

```
module.exports = async (deployer, network, accounts) => {
   console.log(network);
   console.log(accounts);// also useful to have this at hand

}
```

Comment: This won't work. `network` will be equal to `dashboard` but what I want is to get name or ID of the network selected in the Metamask. I would need to somehow get to the `web3` object injected to Truffle

Comment: I see, in that case, `web3.eth.net.getId()` would get it straight from your connection. You can find the docs @ https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth-net.html#web3-eth-net

There is also web3.eth.getChainId() depending what suits you best. Good Luck

Comment: Yea, but is it possible to get the web3 object from the Truffle migration file?

Comment: I think I got this thanks to your answer. I used this post https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle-migrate/issues/28#issuecomment-735521238 and now I can see the chain Id on my currently connected network. But I have one more question. Is this is proper way to get the web3 object? I mean using the Migrations.interfaceAdapter

Comment: Truffle sets a global instance of web3 on your tests and migrations. you can just use it. Its already connected to the network you specified on  the command `truffle migrate --network somenetowork`  & along with your truffle config